# Stop object field validation on first failure

Tags: java, validation, oval

I'm using [OVAL](http://oval.sourceforge.net) as object validation framework in my project. Let's say I have the following object:

```
public class MyObject {

    @NotNull(message = "Amount cannot be null.")
    @NotNegative(when = "groovy:((_value != null) && (_value.getAmount() <= 0))", message = "Amount cannot be ZERO or negative.")
    private Currency amount;
}
```

Without specifying **(_value != null)** in @NotNegative annotation it fails with java.lang.NullPointerException even though there is additional @NotNull annotation which should check that case.

Is it possible somehow to avoid that duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Checks should be ignored if the field is `null`. You should open a bug report at http://sourceforge.net/p/oval/bugs/